# (C++)How do I create a function that receives two sorted linked lists and returns a third list of elements appearing in both lists?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Because this is an assignment, I can not use STD::List.

Struct List::Node is private so I can't access it from the compareLists function. How can I use the getHead() function to pass the head pointer for each list to a variable I can use to navigate through the list?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<list>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

void compareLists(List L1, List L2){
    List::node* L1HeadPtr = L1.getHead();
    List::node* L2HeadPtr = L2.getHead();
}
```

List.h:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

class List {
private:

 struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
  };

  node* head;
  node* curr;
  node* temp;

public:

  List();
  void AddNode(int addData);
  void DeleteNode(int delData);
  void PrintList();
  node* getHead();
};
 #endif // LIST_H
```

Separate file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

List::List(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

List::node* List::getHead(){
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Its C++, use std::list.

Comment: Is there any specific reason not using std::list?

Comment: One option is [declare `compareLists` to be a friend of `List`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) Another is to make `compareLists` a member function. I think I prefer `friend` here.

Comment: Unless this is a school/collage exercise start from here `std::set_intersection`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Comment: It is for a school exercise or else I would use std::list. Also, I haven't learned friend yet.

Comment: [OT]: Rule of 5/3/0. (even if your currently don't broke it as you leak...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct node` is indeed in private section of `List`,
whereas you provide public getter `List::node* List::getHead()`.

So from outside of the class, we cannot use name `List::node`. we can work around that using `auto`:

```
void compareLists(const List& L1, const List& L2){
    const auto* L1HeadPtr = L1.getHead();
    const auto* L2HeadPtr = L2.getHead();
    // ...
}
```

Simpler and more intuitive would be to move struct `List::node` in public section (as you provide `getHead()`):

```
class List {
public:
 struct node {
    int data;
    node* next = nullptr;
  };

private:
  node* head = nullptr;

public:

  List();
  void AddNode(int addData);
  void DeleteNode(int delData);
  void PrintList() const;
  node* getHead();
};
```

but unfortunately, with your getter `getHead()`, you broke encapsulation of your class as `node*` content can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a school exercise (because otherwise, USE `std::list`), this is a classic case of publishing an iterator, like this:

```
List::node* List::NextNode(List::node* curr) {
    return (curr == NULL) ? head : curr->next;
}
```

And the use it in your `compareLists`:

```
void compareLists(List L1, List L2) {
    List::node* iter1 = NULL;
    List::node* iter2 = NULL;

    while ((iter1 = L1.NextNode(iter1)) != NULL &&
           (iter2 = L2.NextNode(iter2)) != NULL)
    {
        if (iter1->data == iter2->data) {
            // Use shared item
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: struct node is in the private section of List, so I can't use List::node* in this function